# Get key from spinner firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-spinner

I don't why I am getting the last key value from the spinner. How can I get the key of the selected item from the spinner?

I have seen a tutorial like this, but it haven't worked for me. 
Thank you for answering. I really need your help here guys.

Here is my code

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                if (!snapshot.hasChild("keyRoom")) {

                String tenant = snapshot.child("usertype").getValue(String.class);
                if (tenant.equals("Tenant")) {

                    final Object t = snapshot.getKey();
                    Tenant data = snapshot.getValue(Tenant.class);
                    names.add(data.getFname() + " " + data.getMname() + " " + data.getLname());

                        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
                        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(AddTenant.this, String.valueOf(t), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: show `onItemSelected` function

Comment: I did that, but t does not work for me

Comment: @phpdroid was asking you to post your onItemSelected function. That is how you can retrieve the key of the selected item from a spinner. So if you can show us what you have written we can see what is wrong with it.